# Insert multiple values to a cell 1 by 1

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

I'm new to SQL, and I'd like for a user with permission to add an ID to a column. This is for a Discord bot. The way I have it setup is so each guild (server) gets their row with the guild ID as guildId and the channel ID as channelId.

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'whitelist channel')) {
    var args = message.content.split(/\s+/g).slice(1);
    let cID = args[1];
    let gID = message.guild.id;
    sql.run(`UPDATE guilds SET channelId = ${cID} WHERE guildId = ${gID}`)
message.channel.send(`Whitelisted channel: <#${cID}>`)
```

Currently, the code will overwrite any value in channelId, and I'd like to have them comma seperated. This works when I edit the DB myself, so I figure it's possible to do through the bot as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place your query like this

```
`UPDATE guilds SET channelId = channelId || ',' || ${cID} WHERE guildId = ${gID}`
```

|| is concat operator in sqllite...